# Has someone created a WPF Toolbar-Control in Vista/Win7 look?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows-7, user-interface, explorer

I would like to add a toolbar, that looks like the one in the Windows 7 Explorer (see picture below), to a WPF-application. Because I'm new to WPF I wondered if there is a WPF-Control (free / open source) I can use instead of having to create a new one.
I already searched for it but could not find anything useful.

[alt text http://www.pic-upload.de/23.04.09/juv56l.png](http://www.pic-upload.de/23.04.09/juv56l.png)

Answer (score 3):

You could just re-style the WPF TabControl to look like that. It's not very hard, just setting the Background with a nice LinearGradientBrush could get you very close to that.

Here's a (crappy colors) example:

```
<ToolBar>
   <ToolBar.Background>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
         <GradientStop Color="White" Offset=".1" />
         <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset=".3" />
         <GradientStop Color="LightSteelBlue" Offset=".8" />
      </LinearGradientBrush>
   </ToolBar.Background>
</ToolBar>
```

Even better if you put it in a style.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't trying to fake the Windows UI; you should be calling `ThemeServices` to draw it for you.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the image didn't work, here's the link

http://www.pic-upload.de/23.04.09/juv56l.png